# Execute terminal command flex

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command

my problem looks like this. I would like to run a program written in Flex to analize some files. To do that i tried:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(MYCOMMAND);

THREAD...

p.waitFor();
```

my command looks like this

```
Flex/Tokenizacja/Tokenizacja < Przyklady/Wejscie/Wejscie1.java > Przyklady/Wyjscie/Wejscie1.txt
```

when i run this command it gets stuck (no error message, it is just waiting for something). the Flex program works fine when i run in from the terminal. I tried to make the Paths shorter (in the same location) but it does not work to. please help.

Comment: You should edit your question so that code/outputs are easier to see.

Comment: Try http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html

Comment: it does not work. i think that it opens the Flex program and it waits for input, but i dont know how to send something to it. when i open the Flex program from the terminal without sending ane input to it then it bahaves similar- it does not give any output ultil i give some input to it. i treid input/output streams but i did not help- maybe i did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("./Flex/Tokenizacja/Tokenizacja").redirectInput(new File(PATH_TO_TXT_FILE)).redirectOutput(new File(PATH_TO_OTHER_TXT_FILE)).start();
```